# How to count documents in pymongo with different names

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I have a document formatted as below. I am trying to get most used command in `discord` and this is my `mongodb` collection format. I am using `pymongo`. Previously I used postgresql, but because of the problems in hosting, I shifted to `mongodb`.

Any help would be appreciated...

```
{
                'guild': guild_id,
                'channel': ctx.channel.id,
                'author': ctx.author.id,
                'used': message.created_at,
                'prefix': ctx.prefix,
                'command': command,
                'failed': ctx.command_failed,
            }
```

Now the problem is I want to fetch a query...

```
query = """SELECT command,
                          COUNT(*) as "uses"
                   FROM commands
                   WHERE guild_id=$1
                   GROUP BY command
                   ORDER BY "uses" DESC
                   LIMIT 5;
                """
```

I am searching this for hours, and still I didn't get the results..

Answer (score 0):

You can use [mongo aggregations](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/aggregation/)

In your case it can be handled with the following mongo query:

```
db.getCollection('yourCollection').aggregate([
     {$match:{"guild": guild_id}},
     {$group:{_id: "$command", uses:{$sum: 1}}},
     {$sort: {"uses": -1}},
     {$limit: 5}
])
```

To adjust this query in pymongo you can take a look at [here](https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/examples/aggregation.html).

Comment: Thanks for answering, well I figured it out already 

Answer (score 0):

```
records = db.Collection.aggregate(
            [{"$match": {"guild": guild_id}}, {"$unwind": "$command"},
             {"$group": {"_id": "$command", "uses": {"$sum": 1}}},
             {"$sort": SON([("uses", -1), ("_id", -1)])}, {"$limit": 5}])
records = await records.to_list(length=5)
```

Well this should be in case of python.